# Code::Blocks debugger

Tags: debugging, codeblocks

I am having great difficulty running the Code::Blocks debugger.  I have the options set to produce debugging symbols, but for some reason the Run debugger is grayed out.  If anyone has any experience with the debugger I would love to hear from them.

Comment: Perhaps the debugger executable is not specified in your toolchain settings?

Comment: gdb.exe is specified in the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Well that's interesting... Code::Blocks only lets you debug when in a project.  I was trying to debug a single file -_- My mistake.